# Get first 5 lines of a file, using a file of program names as input (Unix)

Tags: shell, unix

Goal: using an input file with a list of file names, get the first 5 lines of each file and output to another file. Basically, I'm trying to find out what each program does by reading the header.

Shell: Ksh

Input: myfile.txt

```
tmp/file1.txt
tmp/file2.txt
```

Output:

```
tmp/file1.txt - "Creates web login screen"
tmp/file2.txt - "Updates user login"
```

I can use "head -5" but not sure how to get the input from the file. I'm assuming I could redirect (>> output.txt)the output for my output file.

Input file names use a relative path.

Update: I created a script below but I'm getting "syntax error: unexpected end of file". The script was created with VI.

```sh
#! /bin/sh
cat $HOME/jmarti20.list | while read line
do
  #echo $line" >> jmarti20.txt
  head -n 5 /los_prod/$line >> $HOME/jmarti20.txt
done
```

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: "Creates web login screen" doesn't look like "5 lines", more like a single line.

Comment: Also, `/tmp/file1.txt` looks like an absolute path.

Comment: How do I get input from a file as input to my "head -5" command? In the response from hellork, "file1.txt" is a file with the names of files. 5 lines is in general. Sometimes it will be 1 sometimes more than 5.

Answer (score 0):

Right, you can append output with `>>` to a file.

```
head -n 5 file1.txt >> file_descriptions.txt
```

You can also use `sed` to print lines, from documentation at `pinfo sed`.

```
sed 5q file1.txt >> file_descriptions.txt
```

Personal preference is to put file description in line 3, and only print line 3 of files.

```
sed -n 3p file1.txt >> file_descriptions.txt
```

*The reasoning for using line 3 has to do with the first line often containing a "shebang" like #!/bin/bash, and the 2nd line having localization strings, such as `# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-`, to allow proper display of extra character glyphs and languages in terminals and text editors that support them.*

Comment: Great response! How do I input a list of files instead of "file1.txt"? Meaning I have a file from another process that generated a bunch of file names.

Comment: You could use a `while` loop and `read` command to put each input line in a `$filename` variable, and append that to the output file.
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Answer (score 0):

Below is what I came up with and seems to work fairly well:

```
#! /bin/sh
cat $HOME/jmarti20.list | while read line
do
  temp=$line
  temp2=$(head -n 5 /los_prod/$line)
  echo "$temp" "$temp2" >> jmarti20.txt
  #echo "$line" >> jmarti20.txt
  #head -n 5 /los_prod/$line >> $HOME/jmarti20.txt
done
```